# Percentile or actual values for multiple regression in studies involving children?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, biostatistics, quantiles

I have to perform multiple regression where the outcome variable is a non-negative continuous health variable (call it `yvar`) which is in the range of 50-150, and age, gender, height and weight as predictor variables. The age range is 5 to 15 years (a study of children).

Since height and weight are closely related to age (and to gender to a lesser extent) can I use height and weight as such in the equation or do I need to calculate height and weight percentiles for each subject and put those in the equation?

I would also like to know the relative effects of height and weight on `yvar`. For this I think using height_percentile and weight_percentile would be more useful because then the coefficients can be directly compared.

The possible equations are:

```r
lm(yvar ~ age + gender + height + weight, data=mydata)
    
lm(yvar ~ height_percentile + weight_percentile, data=mydata)
```

Age and gender are not added to second equation since percentiles have been calculated for each age and gender group.

Comment: How do you expect the outcome variable to be related to height and weight?  Should the relationship be linear or not?  If nonlinear, do you have any sense of what the formula might be?

Comment: @whuber : I expect the relation to be reasonably linear in this age group.

Comment: Then, unless the percentile map is linear, too (in which case it would not matter which choice of method you made to express the values), wouldn't using the percentiles destroy that linearity?